Determine distribution for GAMMS
I've collected eye-tracking data in a visual world experiment, i.e. subjects fixated a screen with four objects while listening to a sentence, and I analyse from when on they look more at the target object than at the competitor and distractor objects.
I have time-series data and I am analysing empirical logits of proportion of looks (do they look at the target object or to one of the three other objects) with GAMMS (using bam()). There are several items per conditions and there are five different conditions (within-subject), which are expected to affect how early the subject should start looking more and more to the target compared to the three other objects.
The model looks like this (Note that the purpose of this "base" model is to get the value of the autocorrelation parameter rho, and then re-compute a model including this parameter).
gamm.base_L1 <-  bam(IA_1_ELogit ~ condition 
                         + s(Time, by=condition, k=21)
                         + s(Time, Subject, by=condition, bs="fs", m=1)
                         + s(Time, Item , bs="fs", m=1),
                         data = DatPred,
                         discrete = TRUE)

Unfortunately, the residuals are not anywhere close to a normal distribution, as shown in the density plot and QQ plot below. I have also tried to use family = "scat", but this is not close to a t-distribution neither.
Does anyone know if any other family might help?


Please note that I have already run the model with a binomial family using the proportion data (where IA_1_P is the proportion of looks to the target object)
  gamm.base_L1_bn <-  bam(IA_1_P ~ condition 
                            + s(Time, by=condition, k=20)
                            + s(Time, Subject, by=condition, bs="fs", m=1) 
                            + s(Time, Item, bs="fs", m=1),
                            data = DatPred, weights = Obs, 
discrete = TRUE,family = "binomial")

and I get very similar density and QQ plots (see below), which I get via this function from the package itsadug.
check_resid(gamm.base_L1_bn, split_pred=c("Subject","Item"))



Running the main model including the rho term and the AR.start term still leads to this distribution problem.

Based on the fact that the residuals are bimodal it seems more likely that there is systematic variation or confounding that your model is not capturing.

Can you expand on what you mean by modelling the empirical logits of counts? Things would be improved if you shared the code for the model you are fitting. While I agree that something seems missing from the model, a model for did they look or not (0/1) would seem to need a binomial distribution not an unbounded Gaussian or scaled t. Likewise if it is a count of the number of times they looked out of the number of trials; a binomial would seem to be the appropriate choice. That could explain the bimodality too

Thanks, Gavin, I have edited my question with more information. I also thought that the binomial family would be correct even with the empirical logits, but I had been told differently by a reviewer. ;-) So thanks for confirming.

Perhaps you could instead consider a mixture distribution using a GAMLSS, which allows you to custom build a distribution of your choosing, if you have a defensible reason to use one (e.g. you don't have a clear-cut predictor missing which is contributing to this issue).

See this article for a decent discussion on the topic.

It seems likely that the unusual distribution of the residuals is due to deviations in the empirical data, which can frequently occur when working with empirical logits. There isn’t a well-known distribution that exactly matches what you're describing, though it might resemble a Cauchy distribution. However, be cautious if considering this, as the Cauchy distribution does not have a defined expected value, which could complicate interpretation and further analysis.
